# pytest test with --ignore and --junitxml generate xml with ignored tests

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

I am using pytest with --ignore and --junitxml options to generate a report of the test cases those are not ignore but when my report is generated, It also takes into account the ignored tests.

I am using the following command

`pytest --ignore=tests/test_a.py --junitxml=pytest_not_a.xml`

Comment: Hi @MrBeanBremen , I am able to run the above pytest command but while the junit generate the report on gitlab report it keeps the --ignore test file's test as skipped ones and it also takes those into percentage calculations.

Comment: Hm, I don't know - I just tested it locally, and the ignored test is not referenced in the generated xml. Sorry, no idea what may be different in your setup...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am able to resolve this using `pytest.mark.httpapi`, so rather than using it over each test suite. I added `pytest_collection_modifyingitems` which puts the marker on the test on run time.

```
def pytest_collection_modifyitems(config, items):
    for item in items:
        if 'test_a.py' in str(item.fspath):
            mark = getattr(pytest.mark, "httpapi")
            item.add_marker(mark)
            item.add_marker(pytest.mark.common)
```

Now the above command would be slightly changed like

`py.test -v -m "not httpapi" --junitxml=pytest_not_a.xml`. Now the Junit gitlab artifacts only takes the processed tests and do not include skipped tests in success rate calculation.